# How to show the contents of a GET request when you don't know the source?

Tags: php

This might be a dumb question... but my script receives POST data using `$q = $_POST['q'];` and works with that. But sometimes during runtime, my script receives GET requests from somewhere. I'm trying to work out where they are coming from.

How can I assign the contents of the GET request to a variable when I don't know how that GET request is structured?

I know that my POST requests are structured as q= so I have `$q = $_POST['q'];`
But since I don't know the origin of the GET request how can I assign it to a variable so I can see what it is? (I will write the contents to the log when I am able to do this)

Comment: Get parameters are part of the URL. Could you not just print the entire contents of the `$_GET` variable to your log?

Comment: `$_REQUEST['']` will help you for both post and get params

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.. would it just be like $g = $_GET?

Comment: yes, if you will print like `var_dump($_GET);`, you will get what get params are sending

Comment: If you don't know the origin of the get requests why do you want to process them? Sounds a bit dodgy to me. Get requests can be injected into the URL by anybody. If you want log them, just log the URL.

Comment: The GET requests are happening like clockwork about 1 minute into running the script and coming from my IP, so trying to see if the contents will help me find the source.

Comment: @user2721465 just log the URL, the GET parameters will be in there and are quite easy to read. Post an example, somebody may recognise the request.

Comment: Hmm, just showing a blank referrer or an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<pre>
<?php
print_r($_GET);
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's just showing Array() ... an empty array

Comment: Then there are no GET parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
if( ! empty($_GET)) {
    foreach($_GET as $key => $val) {
        echo "$key: $val<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'GET') === 0){
    $getVars = var_export($_GET, true);
    //Do what what you want to do with $getVars.
}
```